# Unity create a permanent access to an gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in many of my scripts I have to deal with the playerObject. I don't want to search for it in each script.

I thought about creating an static class to have permanent access to the player.

This is how I do it

```
public class Globals
{
    public static GameObject playerObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(StringCollection.PLAYER); // The playerObject

    public static Rigidbody playerRigid = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(StringCollection.PLAYER).GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
} // The rigidbody of the player
```

So I want to store all the variables that I need many times. When loading a new scene, it says the rigidbody tries to access an object, that got destroyed previously.

How can I fix it?

I thought about creating an object inheriting from Monobehaviour that gets never destroyed but then I would have to create a reference to it in all my scripts..

Comment: I suggest you look into singletons.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that inherits from Unity's `UnityEngine.Object` are destroyed even when made `static`.

If you want it to stay, you have to call `DontDestroyOnLoad` on it. In this case call:

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(Globals.playerObject);
```

This should make the `playerObject` and every component that is attached to it to stay through the next scene.

Comment: But I would have to call this in a Start method no? So static classes can not call the Start method because they don't inherit from Monob. right?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you call it. As long as you call that before loading the next scene that should be fine.